# JavaScript JQuery Ajax Issue: POST Works fine in Firefox, IE, Safari but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, http-post

I'm new to JavaScript, and working on a hobby project with a few developers. We have a simple page that is used to submit requests to a database.

I decided to try learning JQuery, and started implementing some AJAX functionality into this request page. It works fine in FireFox, IE and Safari, but for some odd reason, I can't get it to work in Chrome.

I've been debugging it for a couple of hours now, and I have no idea why it's not working. Here's the relevant part of the HTML form (post action removed due to JavaScript):

```
        <form method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="amount" value="0" size="7" />
            <input type="submit" value="Fulfill!" /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="index" value="69" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item" value="Iron Ore" />
        </form>
```

And here's the PHP form that it posts to:

```
<?php
require_once("../classes/Database.php");
$database = new Database();

$amount = $database->sanitizeString($_POST['amount']);
$index = $database->sanitizeString($_POST['index']);
$username = $database->sanitizeString($_POST['username']);
$item =  $database->sanitizeString($_POST['item']);
$database->connect();
$database->setRequest($amount, $index, $username, $item);
$database->setKarma($username, $amount, $item);
?>
```

And most importantly, here's my newbie JavaScript code that's simply in the HTML file:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var amount = 0;
    var index = 0;
    var item = 0;
    var username = "";
    var data = "";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form input[type=submit]").click(function(){
            amount = $(this).siblings("input[name=amount]").val();
            index = $(this).siblings("input[name=index]").val();
            item = $(this).siblings("input[name=item]").val();
            username = "<?=$_SESSION['username']; ?>";
            //var stuff = $.post("pages/ajaxfulfill.php", {amount:amount,index:index,item:item, username:username}, function(data){alert(data)}, "html");
            var stuff = $.ajax(
                                    {
                                        url: "pages/ajaxfulfill.php",
                                        type: "POST", data:"amount=" + amount + "&index=" + index + "&item=" + item + "&username=" + username,
                                        success: function(data)
                                        {
                                            alert("Success")
                                        },
                                        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                                        {
                                            alert("error" + XMLHttpRequest.status);
                                            alert("error" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                                        }
                                    }
                               )
            $(this).parents("td").text("Submitted");

        });

    });

</script>
```

At first, I was using the commented out $.post function, which works with the above mentioned browsers. I attempted to switch to the $.ajax function during my debug process, and found out that FF, IE, and Safari always return a "Success" alert, whereas Chrome is returning an Error with status 0 and a blank response.

Being a JavaScript newbie, I'm completely lost at why this would fail. If anyone could point me in the right direction, you'll have my profound respect and well wishes. Thanks.

Comment: Not related directly to the question but consider escaping strings before emitting them to JavaScript. In this case, for example (a) your code will break with any username having apostrophes in it and (b) users will be able to inject arbitrary code in your javascript with clever enough usernames, therefore exploting the XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Sorry it's not an apostrophe, it's a quotation mark in this case but the rest still applies.

Comment: DrJokepu, thank you for pointing that out. I'm sanitizing PHP related stuff, but completely forgot about sanitizing JavaScript related input.

Comment: The nice folks below showed me how to debug, but I'm even more confused now -- when I debug it, the script works perfectly. When I step through the code line by line, it works flawlessly. When it's being run, it fails.

What does this mean?!

Comment: There is a race condition between the XMLHttpRequest being serviced and you unloading the page due to a form submission. Single-stepping through delays the submission until after the XHR's response is ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't seem to be preventing the default action on the submit button. So after your click function fires, the form still submits, presumably cancelling your XMLHttpRequest.

(What might make a difference cross-browser here is that at the end of the function you remove the form from the page by calling the `text()` function. Should that stop the form getting submitted? Don't know... some browsers might, but there is no specification that says so.)

Use `event.preventDefault();` on the argument passed into the handler `function(event) { ... }` to stop the button click going through to submit the form.

But don't bind form submission code to an input button. Your script may (depending on browser and other attributes of the form) fail to fire on another kind of submission such as an Enter press. Always bind validation and AJAX-form-replacement using the `submit` event on the `form` itself. `event.preventDefault();` still applies.

Omitting the `action` attribute of a `<form>` is invalid; the browser typically chooses the existing page's URL to submit to. If you want form fields without a form to submit (and you don't need radio inputs), just omit the `<form>` element. But really you should be using progressive enhancement: make the form work from plain HTML first, with a proper `method="POST" action="ajaxfulfill.php"`, and *then* build a trivial AJAX function on top of that.

```
username = "<?=$_SESSION['username']; ?>";
```

Script injection. Instead:

```
username= <?= json_encode($_SESSION['username'], JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>
```

And:

```
data:"amount=" + amount + "&index=" + index + "&item=" + item + "&username=" + username,
```

You would need to use `encodeURIComponent(...)` over each of the values in a URL-encoded-form-submission, or special characters will break it. Better to let jQuery do that for you:

```
data: {amount: amount, index: index, item: item, username: username},
```

or even simpler, drop all the manual reading of `field.val()` and just use the existing [serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) function that does it all for you:

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

(Assuming `this` is now the `form` you're handling `onsubmit` for... if it were the submit button, you'd have to say `$(this.form)`.)

Do you really want to be taking the username from user-submitted POST data, which they might have changed? Unless usernames are deliberately security-free, it would seem a better idea to get it from the session whence it came.

Comment: You sir, are a gentlemen and a genius. I've modified my script and got it working. I've taken your other suggestions to heart and will be modifying my script accordingly.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: wow. thank you!! I just spent 3 hours trying to figure out what was going in, and your post fixed it in 1 second. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

First thing that you need to do is isolate the problem. Chrome v4.0.249.27 (on OS X, at least) comes with developer tools that you'd probably find useful. See what Chrome is doing when you click that button. You might also want to add ".ajax" to the list of "watched expressions" in the "Scripts" tab of the Developer Tools.

The Developer Tools can be found through **View** » **Developer** » **Developer Tools**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a few things to diagnose this yourself:

1. Shift + Ctrl + J in Chrome to launch the Javascript console and enable debugging. Stick breakpoints and step through your function
2. Watch the Javascript error/warnings console (even in your other browsers)

Comment: Thank you. I've never used Chrome before today, so I did not know about this.

But one thing that has me even more confused.

I debugged it, line by line, stepping over each expression. When I debug it this way, the code works! However, when I run it without debugging, it fails?!

What does this mean?

Comment: @foo it works because stepping through the code gives the form time to submit itself before you remove it from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old post, but I have just had similar symptoms in my project and ended up here trying to find a solution.

I followed some of the advice here about debugging and realised that Chrome does not update the same as other browsers. Changes I had made in the js code, and css were instantly updated in Safari and Firefox with a normal refresh, but Chrome needs a Hard Reload and Cache clear before it updated those same items.

I'm not saying this is the cure for all the issues mentioned above, but it solved my problem.